# How to connect graphiql to another implementation other than javascript

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

i have created a graphql endpoint using graphql-java implementation, i've also installed and run graphiql, but i have no idea how to connect graphiql to my graphql endpoint. could someone please put me through on how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GraphiQL expects particular HTTP endpoint shape by default. You can find the actual HTTP request here:

https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/blob/master/example/index.html#L93

You can customize it in `index.html`, if your graphql-java based endpoint has a different shape, or you can add another HTTP endpoint that has following shape:

- HTTP method: `POST`
- URL path: `/graphql`
- `POST` body is a JSON document that contains following fields:

  - `query` - String - the GraphQL query itself
  - `oprationName` - String (optional) - in case you have several named operations in a query, this field controls which one should be executed
  - `variables` - String | Object (optional) - JSON Object that contains variables for a query execution

Here is an example of request that you may get from GraphiQL

```
POST /graphql
{
  "query": "query Fooo($humanId: String!) {\n  human(id: $humanId) {\n    id\n    name\n  }\n}",
  "variables": "{\n  \"humanId\": \"1000\"\n}",
  "operationName": "Fooo"
}
```